# Debugging a lerna-typescript project in VSCode

Tags: typescript, debugging, visual-studio-code, lerna

I'm trying to build a monorepo using lerna+typescript, I'm using this repo as a start: https://github.com/Izhaki/mono.ts

What i'm trying to achieve is to debug the code inside visual studio code. I've tried something to add the `launch.json` like this:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug",
            "preLaunchTask": "npm: build",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/packages/line/src/index.ts",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "smartStep": true,
            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/packages/line/dist/**/*.js"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm getting some error about he import and the use of:

```
/Users/davidericci/Desktop/mono.ts-master/packages/line/dist/index.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { getDistance } from '@geo/point';
                                                                     ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

so I've changed inside the `tsconfig.build.json` (inside packages):

```
"target": "es2017",
"module": "commonjs",
```

and inside the `tsconfig.base.json` (always inside packages):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es2015", "es2016", "dom", "es2017", "es6", "es5"],
    "noUnusedLocals": true
  }
}
```

but i'm still getting:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:605
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '@geo/point'
```

as error, I think because inside the code (even in the JS code) the import still points to the typescript. I may be wrong here.

all other settings are default for that project.

can be something with `tsconfig-paths`? or is just some setting inside the launch.json?

Thank you very much guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I had to drop the idea of using https://github.com/Izhaki/mono.ts

Using standard config files I managed to succeed in debugging with lerna and even using serverless offline.

This are my files:

`launch.json`

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Debug ms-locations",
      "preLaunchTask": "npm: lerna-tsc",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/packages/ms-locations/lib/sample.js",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "outFiles": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/packages/ms-locations/**/*.js"
      ],
      "protocol": "inspector",
    }
```

`tsconfig`

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "es6", /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017','ES2018' or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs", /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
    "lib": [
        "es6"
    ], /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
    "declaration": true, /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    "declarationMap": true, /* Generates a sourcemap for each corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    "sourceMap": true, /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": false, /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "noImplicitAny": true, /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    /* Additional Checks */
    "noUnusedLocals": true, /* Report errors on unused locals. */
    "noUnusedParameters": true, /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
    "noImplicitReturns": true, /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
    "esModuleInterop": true, /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    "incremental": true
},
"exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "packages/ms-api/test/*.ts"
]
```

}

inside my package folder, if you need to use serverless
this is the tsconfig

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
  "outDir": "./lib",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "noUnusedLocals": false,
  "noUnusedParameters": false,
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
  "sourceMap": true,
      "target": "es2017",
  "esModuleInterop": true,
      "incremental": false
  },
  "include": [
      "./src"
  ]
}
```

I will flag this as the accepted answer even if is not totally compelling the question, but this was my solution.

Hope helps someone

Comment: When you say the first tsconfig do you mean in the root?

Answer (score 2):

I am using the below configuration in a Turborepo monorepo. 2 Nestjs apps, 1 NextJs app. I am using "type": "node-terminal" and then running my standard dev command in each repo using "command": "yarn dev --filter=app_name". I don't see why this pattern couldn't be used for lerna

launch.json

```
    {
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node-terminal",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug Api",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "command": "yarn dev --filter=api",
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/apps/api/**/*.js",
                "!**/node_modules/**"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "node-terminal",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug Api Gateway",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "command": "yarn dev --filter=api-gateway",
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/apps/api-gateway/**/*.js",
                "!**/node_modules/**"
            ]
        },
    
        {
            "name": "Debug client",
            "type": "node-terminal",
            "request": "launch",
            "command": "yarn dev --filter=client",
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "pattern": "started server on .+, url: (https?://.+)",
                "uriFormat": "%s",
                "action": "debugWithChrome"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I seemed to make mine work with a slightly different approach, avoiding lerna (despite being a monorepo using Lerna).

Here is my `launch.json`:

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Test show",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "address": "localhost",
      "protocol": "inspector",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/services/shows",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/serverless/bin/serverless",
      "args": [
        "invoke",
        "local",
        "-f",
        "get",
        "-p",
        "./mocks/get-event.json"
      ],
      "outFiles": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/services/shows/.webpack/service/src/get.js"
      ],
      "autoAttachChildProcesses": true
    }
  ]
}
```

And my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es2017"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "strict": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "outDir": ".build"
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Hope this helps you or others!

Comment: Hi and thanks for the reply!
In the end I used a configuration pretty close to yours to run the lambda on local machine, and having some sort of hot reload using serverless offline.